# Choose optimal subset of size k given certain constraints R

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, linear-programming

I have in R a data.table of size 100K rows and 6 columns (let's say `x_1, ... x_6`).

I am looking for a subset of size 1K rows such that optimizes (maybe not the optimal one, but at least better than random or sorting) how to choose these thousand rows and optimizes `a*sum(x_1) + ... +  f*sum(x_6)`, where `a,...,f` are numbers.

Any suggestion of using an algorithm/library to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Reproducible Example:

```
# Creation of sinthetic data
set.seed(123)
total <- data.frame(id = 1:1000000, x1 =  runif(1000000,0,1),  x2 =  60*runif(100000,0,1), 
                    x3 = runif(100000,0,1), x4 = runif(1000000,0,1), Last_interaction = sample(1:35, 1000000, replace= T))

total$x3 <- -total$x2 * total$x3 * runif(100000,0.7,1)
head(total)

# We are looking for a subset of 1000 rows such that
Cost_function <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4)
{
  0.2*max(x1) + 0.4*sum(x2) - 0.3*sum(x2) - 0.1*max(x4)
}
# is maximized.

# We rank the dataset by weights in cost function
total <- total[with(total, order(-x2, x3,-x1,-x4)), ]
head(total)

# Want to improve (best choice by just ranking and getting top1000) 
result_1 <- total[1:1000,]
# And of course random selection
result_2 <- total[sample(1:nrow(total), 1000,
                          replace=FALSE),]


# Wanna improve sorting and random selection if possible
Cost_function(result_1$x1,result_1$x2,result_1$x3,result_1$x4)
# [1] 5996.787
# (high value, but improvable)
Cost_function(result_2$x1,result_2$x2,result_2$x3,result_2$x4)
# [1] 3000
# low performace
```

Comment: Do you mean "maximizes sum(i selected row) a x_1[i]+..+fx_6[i]"?

Comment: Nope sorry, let me edit it

Comment: In some sense the rows are completely decomposable -- each row adds `a` times its first element plus `b` times its second element plus ... plus `f` times its sixth element to the sum you are trying to optimize. So why not just sort rows by that quantity and take the top 1,000?

Comment: I am creating a reproducible example because I think I didn't explain my trouble properly.

Comment: How can you rank the elements of the vector if the objective function sums over all their values?

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange cost function: `0.2*max(x1) + 0.4*sum(x2) - 0.3*sum(x2) - 0.1*max(x4)`.. I don't think the proposed method to calculate `Ax` (followed by sorting) corresponds to this. The combination of `max` and `sum` in the cost function makes it not separable in the rows so we cannot just use sorting. The only thing I can come up with is a MIP formulation (a binary variable indicating if a row is selected).

The model is not completely trivial:

[image]

See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/01/a-difficult-row-selection-problem.html) for details.

For a small data set it does the following:

[image]

Note that the LP model given in the other answer (now deleted) is not correct (even for all positive values). Modeling the `max` correctly for the non-convex case is not trivial.

Comment: I made a linear function as an example, I didn't work on defining properly the cost function. And I found the error if a decompose ` 0.2*max(x1) + 0.4*sum(x2) - 0.3*sum(x2) - 0.1*max(x4)` value of a is `a= c(0.2,0.1,0,0.1)` instead of `a=c(0.2,0.4,-0.3,0.1)` because I failed copy-pasting.
Thank you for your help guys, very much appreciated.